# web application to multi tenant application one drive business api

Tags: azure, multi-tenant, azure-active-directory, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

my question is similar to question [Multi-Tenant app - OneDrive Business API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34788472/multi-tenant-app-onedrive-business-api)

but i want my application to access the one drive from tenants of other different azure subscription, is it possible? i understood that if i register my application and mark it as multi-tenant, it will allow me access the tenant in my azure subscription, but if i want to access the tenant using the same application but in different azure subscription whats the way.

Answer (score 1):

What’s kind of authentication flow are you using? Normally, we use the Authorization Code Grant Flow that the user delegates access to a web application. In this scenario, to enables the users on other tenants to login the website and access their Office 365 resource, we only need to enable the multiple-tenant app on the Azure portal.

> > but if i want to access the tenant using the same application but in different azure subscription whats the way.

It depends on which REST you were using. It is same as we are call the REST API for the single tenant app if we are using the Microsoft Graph to query the OneDrive for business. The endpoint of the list children of a driveItem is still like below no matter which tenant the user login:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{item-id}/children
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/{item-path}:/children
```

If you were using the Office 365 REST API, we need to discover the service endpoint. You can refer to [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/discovery-service-rest-operations) for more detail about Office 365 Discovery Service REST API.

Comment: hi, i used this sample application https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-connect-rest-sample     and this application is using https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-libraries/ authentication i am good with graph api and could make it work for single tenant who is in my azure subscrition but if  i want to make it work for the tenant who is in my frnds azure subscrition or who is not at all registered i mean the office 365 account of his. is it possible.

Comment: Yes, it is able to work for multiple tenant means that  anyone in any Azure tenant can login to their tenant and use your app.  You just to make sure that you enable the app as multiple-tenant on Azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the permissions that you need normally the tenant admin of the other tenant has to add the application to their own Azure AD. With the newer app model v2 this is quite a lot easier as the admin can simply give consent once in the normal consent screen for the entire tenant. See [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview/) for a mor elaborate explanation of how this would work.